# Attatch a css class to my cursor

Tags: css

I want to make a custom cursor, I have a css class which is exactly what i want to put on my cursor, but I cannot find a way to actually put that class onto my cursor, I am not sure if this is a possibility at all, anyone know how I can do this?

this is my css class.

```
.myicon{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid red;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    right:100%;
    top:-5%;
    position: absolute;
    clear: both;
    content:'';
}
```

is there anyway I can change my cursor to have this class?

Comment: And the documentation did not help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: Assigning an absolute position to a cursor and things like that - how is that meant to work?

Comment: I'm not completely up-to-date with latest CSS features so I may be wrong but I've never heard of the possibility of having the mouse pointer replaced with a DOM element.

Comment: you cannot add class to a cursor :) it's a property of an element, not an element it's like you wanted to add a class to `font-size` or `background`

Answer (score 2):

you can pass url of png image

```
.module {
  cursor: url('path-to-image.png'), auto;   
}
```

Comment: I tried this but of some reason it doesn't recognise the course - error 404, so I was wondering if there is a possibility to just attach a css class

Comment: provide actual path of that image instead of relative path

Comment: is there any way I  can change the size of the image?

Comment: you can make png image as per your size :)